# How do I add %cat to IPython?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just started using IPython and learning from the tutorials. I have created a file but when I use the **%cat** command I get **ERROR: Line magic function `%cat` not found.** When I type %alias it does not list 'cat' as one of the commands. How can I add it to the list?

Comment: Maybe you can use %pycat instead

Answer (score 1):

For command line in ipython, use `!` instead of `%`

```
!ls
!pwd
!cat
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`%alias cat cat`, this makes `%cat` just like typing `!cat`. Really only useful if you have standard flags or arguments or more complex commands, e.g. one of the standard aliases: list files with execute bit set `alias lx ls -F -l -G %l | grep ^-..x`